# Longest chain in directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, expectation

In a random tournament with $n$ nodes, for any pairs of nodes $a$ and $b$, we create either the edge $a\rightarrow b$ or the edge $b\rightarrow a$ with 50-50 probability.

What is the expected length of the longest chain (meaning transitive subtournament)? If there is no nice closed formula, are there good upper bounds?

Comment: To make sure I understand the question correctly: $$ $$ "In a directed graph with $n$ nodes" $\longrightarrow$ does the graph already have arcs before we start creating new arcs? Or are we basically considering a random [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory))? $$ $$ "where a node appearing earlier always beats a node appearing later" $\longrightarrow$ so you mean we have an arc $a_i \to a_j$ whenever $i < j$? So the induced subgraph on the vertices $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ is a [transitive tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#Transitivity)?

Comment: If by "chain" you just mean a directed path, then the answer is $n$. The length of the longest directed path in a random complete directed graph [is a degenerate random variable always equal to $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810380/longest-path-in-directed-complete-graph).

Comment: Random tournament and transitive tournament, yes

Comment: @Karo thanks for the clarification! The question seems to be related to [Ramsey theory of tournaments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#Ramsey_theory). Do we have any reason to believe that a simple answer exists? Is this a textbook problem or a conjecture/research question?

Comment: No reason to believe that a simple answer exists, just something I wonder. Perhaps we can obtain some estimates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: this question is under improvement, in great part thanks to the comment section

---

I am terrible at probabilities (it is my weakest area in maths) but I will give it a shot; I might inspire someone.

I will try to explicitly calculate the probability that the graph has a chain of length $k$ and then we can apply the definition of expected value to compute that.

Fix $k \leq n$, $n$ being the number of vertices of the graph (let us call it $G$).

There are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways of creating an ordered tuple of length $k$ with distinct vertices. The probability of that tuple representing the chain $a_1 \rightarrow a_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow a_k$ is precisely $\frac1{2^{k-1}}$.

This could mean

$$C_k = P(\text{graph has chain of length }k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\frac1{2^{k-1}}$$

I believe that

$$p_k = P(G\text{ has biggest chain of length }k) = P(G \text{ has chain of length }k) - P(G \text{ has chain of length } k+1)$$

Hence

$$p_k = C_k - C_{k+1}$$

and now you would only have to use the definition of expected value. If it were, we'd have

$$\mathbb{E}[\text{size of longest chain}] = \sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot\left(C_k - C_{k+1}\right)$$

The summation is

$$C_1 - C_2 + 2C_2 - 2C_3 + 3C_3 - 3C_4 + \cdots + (n-1)C_{n-1} - (n-1)C_{n} + nC_n = \sum_{k=1}^n C_k$$

Thus we need only to be able to compute $C_k$. The current formula can get $> 1$ for values of $(n, k)$. If you are able to compute $C_k$ correctly, the answer follows from this. Good luck! I will give it more thought as well.

Comment: I think it should be $$ P(G\text{ has biggest chain of length }k) = P(G \text{ has chain of length }k) - P(G \text{ has a chain of length } k+1). $$ Also, the definition of a chain in the question might be something else than you think it is; I'm waiting for a clarification from OP.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn for one, I hope that the definition of chain is what I think; also I agree with your correction; I also believe that would make the summation of the expected value a lot cleaner.

Comment: Also, the formula for $P(\text{graph has chain of length }k)$ is wrong. It gives values that are (much) larger than one (e.g. $n = k = 3$).

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn Even so, do we agree on the fact that the expected value will be that summation, for some $C_k$ to be correctly computed?

Comment: Ehm, yes, that seems to be correct. :-) Frankly, I think you provided a good enough outline of the solution so that OP can fill in the details (finding a formula for $C_k$), so personally I would rephrase the present answer as a hint and call it a day. :P But it's your answer, so it's not up to me.

Comment: By the way, a small mistake persists in the final display equation: $(n-1)C_{n-1}$ should be $(n-1)C_n$.

Comment: Gosh you are right  @JossevanDobbendeBruyn; already corrected that typo. Thanks!

Comment: For $P(\text{graph has chain of length } k)$, I think we need to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle. But then it is a really huge sum...

Comment: @Karo most likely, yes. Maybe some factors of those sums cancel out when you write the final summation...

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in a more general form in:
"Induced Acyclic Tournaments in Random Digraphs: Sharp Concentration, Thresholds and Algorithms", see e.g. https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/dmgt.2014.34.issue-3/dmgt.1758/dmgt.1758.xml